# How to listen for property change of a Java static class

Tags: java, swing, listener, javabeans, propertychangelistener

i'm building a Swing GUI application and i'm trying to change other parts of the GUI when a property in a static class is changed.

This is the class that holds the properties:

```java
package dev.vitto.cna;

import java.beans.*;

public class Project {

    private static PropertyChangeSupport mPcs =
            new PropertyChangeSupport(Project.class);

    private static String projectName = "Progetto senza titolo";

    private static int activeInstrument = 0;

    // ************************ //

    public static void
    addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        mPcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public static void
    removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        mPcs.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    // ************************ //

    public static String getProjectName() {
        return projectName;
    }

    public static void setProjectName(String projectName) {
        if (projectName.length() < 1) {
            projectName = "Progetto senza titolo";
        }
        mPcs.firePropertyChange("projectName",
                Project.projectName, projectName);
        Project.projectName = projectName;
    }

    public static int getActiveInstrument() {
        return activeInstrument;
    }

    public static void setActiveInstrument(int activeInstrument) {
        mPcs.firePropertyChange("activeInstrument",
                Project.projectName, projectName);
        Project.activeInstrument = activeInstrument;
    }

}
```

When i call the `setProjectName()` method from another part of the program i expect it to activate all the other listeners registered like this, for example, in a class that represents a window:

```java
// ... code

Project.addPropertyChangeListener((PropertyChangeEvent event) -> {
     if("projectName".equals(event.getPropertyName())){
         label.setText(event.getNewValue());
     }
});

//... code
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't happen. I have researched a lot and this seems the only correct way to do it. Any idea on how to make it work?

Comment: Your question and code begs another question of mine: why is everything static? This shouldn't be as it breaks OOP rules and makes your code much more susceptible for bugs due to increased cyclomatic complexity. Fix first things first: make all your fields and methods instance fields and methods, except for constants, utility (stateless) methods, and the main method.

Comment: Also note that there is no such animal in Java as a "static" class, with the exception being static nested classes, but that has nothing to do with your code or question. There are *utility* classes that are *stateless* and have only static methods, such as Java's own Math class, but that is not what you should be creating here since your classes do indeed have state, and you're running into problems because you're unable to access this state.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The "Project" class has every method and variable Static because if i make an instance of it in another part of the program then the state will not be the same. For example i need to keep in memory the name of the current open project to read it from completely different classes. If there is a better way to do it then i would happily want to know.

Comment: That is not a reason to make anything static and in fact is a bad "anti-pattern", meaning that you're using static to fix things the wrong way. The solution is to create one instance of this class and then pass it to where it is needed via constructor or method parameters, again not to make anything static (other than what I mentioned above). This means that you likely have other issues in your code that you may need to ferret out.

Comment: One possible solution is to use the "Singleton Pattern", but that carries problems of its own, and I would suggest against using it.

Comment: But regardless, I strongly stand by my suggestions made both above and in my code and answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to make your class and code stateful and OOP-compliant, meaning that most all of the fields and methods in the code that you've posted should be instance fields and methods, with exceptions for constants, utility methods, and the main method.

Side note: you should set your property *before* calling the notify method, so that the property has been properly set when listeners are notified. Also best to use constants for property names so that there can be no chance of typographical errors slipping in.

And so for example:

```
import java.beans.*;

public class Project {
    public static final String ACTIVE_INSTRUMENT = "active instrument";
    public static final String PROJECT_NAME = "project name";
    public static final String DEFAULT_PROJECT_NAME = "Progetto senza titolo";
    private PropertyChangeSupport mPcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private String projectName = DEFAULT_PROJECT_NAME;
    private int activeInstrument = 0;

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        mPcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        mPcs.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public String getProjectName() {
        return projectName;
    }

    public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
        if (projectName == null || projectName.length() < 0) {
            return;
        }
        String oldValue = this.projectName;
        String newValue = projectName;
        this.projectName = projectName;
        mPcs.firePropertyChange(PROJECT_NAME, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public int getActiveInstrument() {
        return activeInstrument;
    }

    public void setActiveInstrument(int activeInstrument) {
        int oldValue = this.activeInstrument;
        int newValue = activeInstrument;
        this.activeInstrument = activeInstrument;
        mPcs.firePropertyChange(ACTIVE_INSTRUMENT, oldValue, newValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed the issue: i instanciated the Project class in the main method of the application and passed it to all the parts of the gui with constructors.
You could add this in the solution so it's easier to read for other people visiting.

Comment: @mrbackslash: there is no formal mention of reference issues (the problem that may be caused by creating multiple instances of this class) in the question itself, but rather just mention of static properties not working, and so I can't place anything of this sort yet into the answer.